# Palindromes: in this program i have to try and figure out if the user input is a palindrome or not

Tags: palindrome

When ever i execute the program the output says not a palindrome when it is a palindrome(only does this when input has spaces or punctuation) can some one tell me where i went wrong in my code?

```
public class Palindromes
{

 public static void main(String[]args)

 {

     ConsoleIO keyboard=new ConsoleIO();

     String word, word2="",terminate;

     int length;


     do

     {

     System.out.print("Enter a string:"); 

         word=keyboard.readLine();

         word=word.toLowerCase();

         word=word.trim();             

         word=word.replaceAll("\\W", "");

         word=word.replaceAll(" ","");

         length=word.length();



         //finding the reverse of the string          

         for(int i=length-1;i>=0;i--)

         {

         word2+=word.charAt(i);

         }



         //checking to see if the string is a palindrome

         if(word.length()==1)

         {

             System.out.println("The string you entered is not a palindrome");



         }

         else if(word.equals(word2))

         {

             System.out.println("The string you entered is a palindrome.");

         } 


         else

         {

             System.out.println("The string you entered is not a palindrome.");

         }



         System.out.print("Do you want to continue (yes or no):");

         terminate=keyboard.readLine();

         System.out.println();

     }

     while(terminate.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

 }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you would have added a tag so it would be obvious what language the code is written in. Many languages have similar syntax; one is left to guess what it is based on some of the constructors and methods you call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd need to account for the punctuation because that will affect the plaindrome test you have. ra.cecar is not otherwise a palindrome. Have you tried adding more lines like the following?

```
word=word.replaceAll(".", "");
word=word.replaceAll("?", "");
word=word.replaceAll("!", "");
word=word.replaceAll("-", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

To end all problem to Palindrome, I've made this Java program that will end all suffering to it. It's in Java so you're in luck. It basically strip every non-word character, put it to lower case just with 13 lines. Hope this help haha! Let's hope other guys would get lucky to find this too.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Palindrome  {
   public static void main(String[]args){
      if(isReverse()){System.out.println("This is a palindrome.");}
      else{System.out.print("This is not a palindrome");}
   }
   public static boolean isReverse(){
     Scanner keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please type something: "); 
      String line = ((keyboard.nextLine()).toLowerCase()).replaceAll("\\W","");
      return (line.equals(new StringBuffer(line).reverse().toString()));
   }
}
```